# Package "alert-notification" has an incompatible peer dependency

Tags: angular15

I'm trying to update my app to angular 15 (and then to 16).

My `package.json` looks like this (partially):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-extensions/password-strength": "11.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.41",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.0.3",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.8.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.8.0",
    "alert-notification": "^1.3.0",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "^1.10.5",
}
```

While running this command:

```
ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15
```

I get this error:

```
                  Package "alert-notification" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^7.2.9" (extended), would install "15.2.9").
                  Package "alert-notification" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^7.2.9" (extended), would install "15.2.9").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
```

Any idea?

Thanks!